# How to set a toggle on linux (True or False) bash command?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, trackpad

I currently assigned my thinkvantage button to turn off tap to click on my trackpad, but I'd like to convert it to a toggle on/off switch.

For the moment, this is the bash command I use to turn it off (or on with CTRL):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click false
```

In other words, ho do I turn this into a conditional toggle switch bash statement?

Comment: Wouldn't you use `gsettings get...` to get the setting?

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click == true` passes `==` and `true` as arguments to the `gsettings` command. Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
class=org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad
name=tap-to-click
status=$(gsettings get "$class" "$name")
status=${status,,} # normalize to lower case; this is a modern bash extension
if [[ $status = true ]]; then
  new_status=false
else
  new_status=true
fi
gsettings set "$class" "$name" "$new_status"
```

Breaking it down into pieces:

- `#!/bin/bash` ensures that the interpreter for this script is bash, enabling extended syntax such as `[[ ]]`.
- The syntax `$( )` is "command substitution"; this runs a command, and substitutes the output of that command. Thus, if the output is `true`, then `status=$(...)` becomes `status=true`.
- The parameter expansion `${name,,}` expands the contents of `name` while converting those contents to all-lowercase, and is only available in newer versions of bash. If you want to support `/bin/sh` or older releases of bash, consider `status=$(printf '%s\n' "$status" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')` instead, or just remove this line if the output of `gsettings get` is always lowercase anyhow.
- The comparison `[[ $status = true ]]` relies on the bash extension `[[ ]]` (also available in other modern ksh-derived shells) to avoid the need for quoting. If you wanted it to work with `#!/bin/sh`, you'd use `[ "$status" = true ]` instead. (Note that `==` is allowable inside `[[ ]]`, but is **not** allowable inside of `[ ]` on pure POSIX shells; this is why it's best not to be in the habit of using it).

Note that whitespace is important in bash! `foo = bar`, `foo= bar` and `foo=bar` are completely different statements, and all three of them do different things from the other two. Be sure to be cognizant of the differences in copying from this example.

Comment: This actually does answer my question fully. However I can't seem to insert it into the keyboard shortcut form in settings. I believe the reason is it is a one line command only. So I tried this >  
class=org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad; name=tap-to-click; status=$(gsettings get "$class" "$name"); status=${status,,}; if [[ $status = true ]]; then;   new_status=false ;else ;  new_status=true; fi; gsettings set "$class" "$name" "$new_status"

But I get a bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;' error when inputing it in the console.

Comment: Put this inside of a script, save the file and mark it executable (chmod +x), and have that one command run the script.

Comment: ...alternately, you could probably take out the extra `;`s and get it to work inline. The one after the `else` is definitely wrong when making a one-liner out of a script, and I think the one after the `then` too. Not sure that's exhaustive; would need to play around a bit.

Comment: You were right about the ;'s. It worked on the console, but I am still struggling with the shortcut though. I will post updates when I make it work. Thanks again.

Comment: With the shortcut, it's probably implemented with `/bin/sh`, not bash, so the extensions don't work. See my notes in the answer about where this uses bash extensions and how to remove them. Or you can just save this in an external script, and the `#!/bin/bash` shebang will make it be properly run with bash.

Comment: (To explain why that would be the case: The conventional way to invoke such things is with the `system()` C library call, and `system()` uses `/bin/sh`).

Answer (score 1):

Toggling seconds on the Ubuntu Unity clock (directly pastable as a command for a keybinding):

`bash -c 'gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-seconds $(gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-seconds | perl -neprint/true/?false:true)'`

For GNOME:

`bash -c 'gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds | perl -neprint/true/?false:true)'`

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/24256/toggle-the-touchpad-on-or-off

```
synclient TouchpadOff=$(synclient -l | grep -q 'TouchpadOff.*1'; echo $?)
```

or

```
tp=$(synclient -l | grep TouchpadOff | awk '{ print $3 }') && tp=$((tp==0)) && synclient TouchpadOff=$tp
```